Saw to cut kitchen plinth
I'm refitting the doors on our kitchen units, and they come with colour matching plinth and kickboard which I need to cut to size.
I don't have any kind of power saw, but it shouldn't be a lot of cutting. However, like most kitchen board it has some kind of coloured veneer which is liable to chip when being sawn.
Is there a particular blade type or grade of hand saw I can get that will allow me to minimise the chipping as I cut? Or a technique to help (I read somewhere about sandwiching it in cardboard although that sounds a right pain)? Or do I really need to invest in a power tool to do this, and if so what kind of power saw and blade do I need?

Put the sawn edge at the top where it's invisible to anyone taller than a kitten.

@Jasen it won't be invisible on wall units

The blade is the most important choice.  You want a fine tooth blade.
Either hand or power saw.  Painters tape will help some.
Power saws usually have guides that help with making a straight, square cut that helps hiding the cut when back together.
Measurement is very important.  A perfect cut 1/32 inch short looks not good.

Also, I believe it matters which face is up when you saw.  I can never remember whether it's finish-up or finish-down, but one direction chips more than the other.
